# How to split string and capture sentences ending using regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split a string and capture sentences ending characters like `.`, `?`, `!` as well.

In other words, my regex separates a string based on whitespace and special characters that English sentence using end with like `.`, `?`, `!` but it should keep these.

I know it is kind confusing so look at array below, in case of 
sentence like this

```
why you are eating too much?
```

The array that stores these words should be like this

```
@word = ( "why", "you", "are", "eating", "too", "much", "?" );
```

but my code output array like this instead

```
@word=("why"," ","you","are","eating","too"," ","much","?","?");
```

code :

```
my $s = "why you are eating too much?";

my @word = split /(\s+|([\s+.?!]))/, $s;

for ( @word ){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to read because the expected input and output are messed up. You don't need to use HTML tags here. Just look at [the formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then please [edit] your question and use code blocks for your input and output.

Comment: Your output does not match the code you show us. Please show your **real** code.

Comment: Please [edit] the real code into the question. Off-site resources can go down and it's just a few lines. Also please fix the question like I said before. Actual people are trying to help you here, but you need to please do your part.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you want to throw away, use `split`.
If you know what you want to keep, use `m//g` in list context.

This looks like a case of the latter:

```
my $str = "why are you eating too much?";
my @words = $str =~ m/[^\s.!?]+|[.!?]/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression instead of using `split()`:

```
(\w+|[\.!?])
```

Here is a sample code in Perl and a [live example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNlhfS3d5Q2ZoSzQ):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "why you are eating too much?";
my @matches = $str =~ /(\w+|[\.!?])/g;
print Dumper \@matches;
```

Comment: that for your help but you code has much? as one item while what i need actually is "much","?" look at my desired output ,just to know what i am talking about

Comment: Okay, then it is even simpler. I've updated the answer.

Comment: you answer works perfect but not in all cases for example if i have sentence like this "why you ,are 'eating' too, much?"  i want to keep all punctuation inside sentence . live example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNlhfS3d5Q2ZoSzQ

Comment: i was trying to split in whitespace and if any of these special characters appears at the end (.?!) i should also store but the same time i want to keep all punctuation in sentence if exists and the whole purpose of that if looked at last item in array i cant tell if it question or regular sentence while maintaining all grammar inside this sentence

Comment: i think that the simplest approach is split string based on whitespace and look at the end of sentence and store whatever special character

Comment: *"if i have sentence like this* **"why you ,are 'eating' too, much?"** *"* That is different from the question you asked. You need to ask a new question and specify your problem properly.